How to git push multiple cargo projects on a single folder?
Ok so this is the structure of my folder I want to git add . and then git push to a repo on GitHub:
projects
|_Project1
|_Project2
|_Project3
|_Project4
|_Project5

The problem is that I am having this error:
error: 'Project1/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed

I created this projects through cargo new Projectx
I suspect is something related that every folder have their own .git file, what is the best way to handle this goal?

"error: 'Project1/' does not have a commit checked out" This means Project1 is a GIt repository by itself; it's very new (no commits); most probably cargo initialized Git repo. Either you push it into its own separate repository or you remove Project1/.git/ directory, add Project1 and push inside projects.

You also have to do git commit after adding files.

@JimRedmond the problem is when I do git add .

Right, but if this is a brand-new repository and you haven't committed anything then you won't have any commits at all, let alone any commits that have been checked out.
